# Does Data Verification Check is needed at user level in BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making Android & MCU(STM32) program and It usually do ble communication by BLE (BLE4.0, HM-10)

I successfully make each of them communicate, but sometimes I am not sure that they are talking correct.

So in every BLE communication, for make it sure, Do I have to set some kind of verification step like CRC or CheckSum ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRC is already performed at the link layer. If you use pairing / bonding, there is an additional 32-bit authentication tag that must be correct. So no you don't need an extra check.